Why my context state is not changing at the time with axios method?
I'm trying to update the context variable using the response of the API that axios is requesting, but it is not updating (I'm using NextJS)
I need this variable to update every time when i open the page, but the the fact is that i'm receiving the default setting of the variable i want to change. The useEffect runs, but for some reason, the setState thing is not working
In this case, the use of useEffect is a must? Is something wrong with axios method? help me please
Is this because of the fact that the {axios.get} method is a promise? If that's the reason, what should i do?
I really tried a lot of things, i need answers for this questions because i really dont know what i am doing wrong
EconomyContext vv

'use client'
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

export const EconomyContext = createContext()

export const EconomyWrapper = ({children}) => {

let [actualBalance, setActualBalance] = useState(
    {
        initialValue: 0,
        standardExpenses: 0,
        actualBalance: 0,
        updated: false
    }
)

return(
    <EconomyContext.Provider value={{actualBalance, setActualBalance}}>{children}</EconomyContext.Provider>
)
}

Component i'm using to change {actualBalance} value:
'use client'

import { useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'

import { EconomyContext } from '../context/EconomyContext'

export default function ActualDetails() {

    const balance = {
        initialValue: 1500.00,
        standardExpenses: 1000.00,
        actualBalance: 500.00
    }

    const {actualBalance, setActualBalance} = useContext(EconomyContext)

    useEffect(() => {

        let standardExpenses = 0

        axios.get("http://localhost:4000/economy/getActualBalance")
        .then((response) => {
            const dbResponse = response.data.success
            response.data.success.forEach((element) => {
                standardExpenses += element.AMOUNT_MONEY
            })

            setActualBalance(
                {
                    initialValue: dbResponse[0].BALANCE,
                    standardExpenses: standardExpenses,
                    actualBalance: dbResponse[0].BALANCE - standardExpenses,
                    updated: true
                }
            )

            console.log(actualBalance)

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })

        console.log(actualBalance) //This log shows me the default actualBalance value setted on the context script

    }, [])
 
    return(... just some react code...)
}

